# How to boot from USB with an Asus P8Z77M motherboard

Tags: usb, bootable-media

I have an ASUS P8Z77M. I have managed to boot from USB but only several times, out of easily 100 times trying, it's very random. I don't know how I managed to boot from USB. It should be easy but there are many settings and I've tried most of them. I've also tried several USB keys.

How can I boot from USB?

Comment: Are these EFI bookable images or boot-able images that require legacy mode to be enabled?

Comment: google the bios make. phoenix or ami or whatever